# jQuery cannot deserialize json object

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have this return come from here

```
 public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "{\"longPachage\":{\"Id\":0}}";
        }
```

and i Receive this return by ajax with this code

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",           
            url: "http://localhost:3148/api/values/5",           
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);                
                alert(" Success ");
            },
            error: function (data) {

                alert(" Error ");
            }
        })
```

what i can to deserialize json object and print the Id value only ?

Comment: Try `data.longPachage.Id`

Comment: Don't attempt to return `json` like that. Return a `JsonResult` of an object instead (and you can remove the pointless `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", ` option)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this:

```
public ActionResult Get(int? id)
{
    return Content("{\"longPachage\":{\"Id\":0}}");
}
```

And then in your jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3148/api/values", {id:5}, function(data) {
    var id = data.longPachage.Id;
    alert(id)
});
```

Comment: JsonResult will not return string :))

Comment: To return json, its `return Json(new { longPachage = new { ID = 0 } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: i cannot understand you

Comment: @OsamaElsayed Which part you cannot?

Comment: this part public JsonResult Get(int id)
        {
            return Json(new { longPachage = new { ID = 0 } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

i don't want change the return i want deserialize this return 
{\"longPachage\":{\"Id\":0}}

Comment: @OsamaElsayed check the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. It may be help to you. 
You are not parse the data to get JSON in string format. So you can now use this code to get JSON data in string format.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);


$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",           
        url: "http://localhost:3148/api/values/5",           
        success: function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(obj.Id);                
            alert(" Success ");
        },
        error: function (data) {

            alert(" Error ");
        }
    })
```

Comment: alert " undefined "

Comment: can you alert obj variable to see what is in the string.

Comment: alert [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

yes, Stephen is right.

you have to send a json result from controller.

for exa.

```
public JsonResult Get(int id)
{
    return Json(new 
    { 
          longPachage = new { ID = 0 } 
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and in your ajax success, just retrieve that object or dataID.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",           
        url: "http://localhost:3148/api/values/5",           
        success: function (data) {
            var dataID = data.longPachage.Id;
            // Do with Your ID.
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //Do anything for error here.
        }
    })
```

Comment: and what is the issue? just put debugger in success function, and see that your dataID has any value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JsonResult in MVC to return Json instead of building a string. JsonResult is just an abstact class of ActionResult. Modify your code in the controller as follows

**Method 1:**

```
public JsonResult GetTest(int id)
{
    return this.Json(new { ID = 0 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

OR

**Method 2:**

Try to create a model class as LongPachage

```
public class LongPachage()
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

and try to invoke into the controller method as follows

```
public JsonResult Get(int id)
    {
        LongPachage model = new LongPachage();
        model.ID = 0;
        return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

OR

**Method 3**

Create Model class say TestModel and try to add LongPachage class as propery of this class.

```
public class TestModel()
    {
       public LongPachage LongPachage {get;set;}
    }
```

and try to invoke into the controller method as follows

```
public JsonResult Get(int id)
    {
        TestModel model = new TestModel();
        model.LongPachage .ID = 0;
        return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and then in the view using AJAX GET wrapper try to implement as follows

```
 $.get('@Url.Action("Get","ControllerName")', { id: "5" })
                .done(function (data) {
                   // If you are using Method 1 or Method 2 alert will be as follows
                    alert(data.ID);
                   // If you are using method 3 
                    alert(data.LongPachage.ID)
                });
```

Comment: return this error The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Can you tell me which method you have used

Comment: Have you included all the sufficient namespaces in your controller